# How to remap 'Switch to next window' shortcut on MacBook Pro with OS X?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, macbook, remapping

On my mac, switch to next window is mapped to CMD + ´. This is a pain when you're using a browser and your focus in on an input field or textarea etc., because when you hit that combo, instead of switching to the next window it types in a ´.

I know you can change keyboard shortcuts from System Preferences but there's no option to change switch to next window (atleast that i could think of).

There exists a tool called KeyRemap4MacBook which you can use to remap single keys. It might be able to also remap keyboard shortcuts but i'm not sure about it.

So, any ideas?